# sql trigger on insert

Tags: sql-server, triggers

quick question, I am building a simple trigger which purpose is to decrement the value of a table field called openSeats, the trigger is executing on insert but I dont know what commands to use to say:
Decrement the value openSeats , where Id is equal to inserted Id

```
USE [Training]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[DecrementSeat]    Script Date: 11/04/2011 14:55:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DecrementSeat]
   ON  [dbo].[personTraining]
   AFTER INSERT

AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_training]
    SET openSeats = openSeats - 1 
    WHERE training_id =
```

END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your trigger:

```
update dbo.tbl_training
set openSeats = openSeats - 1
where training_id in
(
    select training_id
    from inserted
)
```

It utilizes the `inserted` dynamic table that SQL Server populates with inserted data during a trigger.

Comment: The column prefix 'inserted' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query

Comment: thanks , got it working, can you recommend me a good tutorial or book for triggers?

Comment: Here's a great article on triggers to get you started (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx).  Any decent book on SQL Server will have good information as well.  If this solved your answer, please mark as answer.  Glad to help!

Comment: This statement will not handle multi-row inserts appropriately. When an insert statement inserts more than one row for the same `training_id`, the `openSeats` will be decremented by one, rather than by the number of rows inserted for that `training_id`.  Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190752.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger should be able to handle "multi-row" inserts. I expect you want to subtract 1 from openSeats for each row inserted.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_training]
   SET openSeats = openSeats - 
       ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM inserted
          WHERE inserted.training_id = [dbo].[tbl_training].training_id )
 WHERE training_id IN
       ( SELECT inserted.training_id FROM inserted
          WHERE inserted.training_id IS NOT NULL )
```